# Play Forms from case classes

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm new to playframework. I have my model for a User as well as the accompanying object for the static methods...

```
case class User(id: Int, username: String, password: String, fullname: String, /
     lastLogin : Date, updatedOn: Date, updatedBy: Int, createdOn: Date, createdBy: Int)
```

I want to create a form for this class omitting some of the details. Currently I have a UserForm case class

```
case class UserForm(fullName:String, username: String, password:String, confirm:String)
```

To allow me to use:

```
val userForm = Form(
    mapping(
        "fullName" -> of[String],
        "username" -> of[String],
        "password" -> of[String],
        "confirm" -> of[String]
    )(UserForm.apply)(UserForm.unapply)
)
```

This feels kind of `Hacker-ish`. Is there an idiomatic and more conscice way to do this?

Comment: give User case class some default values and/or use "default" or "ignoring" attribs in form mapping, that way you don't need a separate UserForm case class

Comment: Why is this `hacker-ish`? It's a clean separation of form submission and model.

Comment: In my head when I do too much typing(and repetition for that matter) in scala, it's the been the case that I'm usually doing something wrong. @Marius

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
val userForm = Form(
  mapping(
      "fullName" -> text,
      "username" -> text,
      "password" -> text,
      "confirm" -> text
  )(UserForm.apply)(UserForm.unapply)
)
```

There are a lot more built-in checks and validations. The basics are listed here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaForms

If you don't need them in an object you could use a tuple

```
val userForm = Form(
  tuple(
      "fullName" -> text,
      "username" -> text,
      "password" -> text,
      "confirm" -> text
  )
)
```

The tuple in your case you have the following type: `(String, String, String, String)` which you could use like this: `val (fullName, username, password, confirm) = refToTuple`

Answer (score 3):

Late coming to this, but I just released a utility to help with this! Using your classes, your code would look like this:

```scala
case class User(id: Int, username: String, password: String, fullname: String, lastLogin : Date, updatedOn: Date, updatedBy: Int, createdOn: Date, createdBy: Int)
object User { implicit val mapping = CaseClassMapping.mapping[User] }

val userForm = Form(implicitly[Mapping[User]])
```

You can find the source and instructions for including it in your project on github: https://github.com/Iterable/iterable-play-utils